RollupError: Expression expected - React Native and Expo Icons
I have a yarn/lerna monorepository with this react native package that consist in a component library.
When I want to build with rollup, I got this error that comes from a dependency of my package (@expo/icons)
[!] RollupError: Expression expected
../../node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/createIconSet.js (39:27)
37:                 }
38:                 if (!this.state.fontIsLoaded) {
39:                     return <Text />;
                               ^
40:                 }
41:                 return (<RNVIconComponent ref={(view) => {
    at error (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:279:30)
    at nodeConverters (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:2153:9)
    at convertNode (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:1038:12)
    at convertProgram (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:1029:48)
    at Object.parseAstAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:2219:20)
    at Module.tryParseAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14923:21)
    at Module.setSource (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14504:35)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\test\cds-croma\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18798:13)

This is my rollup.config.js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'

export default {
  input: ['src/index.ts'],
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'esm',
    sourcemap: true,
    preserveModules: true
  },
  external: ['react/jsx-runtime', 'react', 'react-native'],
  plugins: [nodeResolve(), commonjs(), typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' })]
}


and this is my tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}


I dont have much expercience with this bundler so any help would be glad.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

I have the project (lerna + rollup) with yarn.
And for imports of icons i use url plugin import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';, e.g. rollup config looks like


import {defineConfig} from 'rollup';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';

import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const PACKAGE_NAME = process.cwd();
const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(PACKAGE_NAME, 'package.json'), 'utf-8'));

const includePaths = ['**/*.woff', '**/*.woff2', '**/*.svg', '**/*.png'];

export default defineConfig({
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: false,
      name: packageJson.name,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: false,
      name: packageJson.name,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
...
    url({
      fileName: '[name][extname]',
      include: includePaths,
      limit: 0,
    }),
  ],
});



You can see more detailed information my repo
